# KKT conditions for a convex optimization (optimal crowdsourcing with budget constraint)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am having some troubles deriving the optimal solution of the following convex optimization problem, $w_j$, $c_{ij}$, and $B$ are fixed and non negative.
\begin{align}
& \underset{n_{ij}}{\text{minimize}}
& & -\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sqrt[]{\sum_{j=1}^{M}n_{ij}w_{j}^2} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \sum_{ij} c_{ij}n_{ij} \leq B\\
&&& n_{ij} \geq 0, \text{ }i=1,...,N,j=1,...,M
\end{align}
I write out the KKT conditions, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the Lagrange multipliers.
\begin{align}
-\frac{w_{j'}^2}{2\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^{M} n_{i'j}w_{j}^2}}+\lambda c_{i'j'}-\mu_{i'j'}&=0, \text{ }i'=1,...,N,j'=1,...,M \\
\lambda &\geq 0\\
\mu_{i'j'}&\geq 0, \text{ }i'=1,...,N,j'=1,...,M\\
\lambda(\sum_{ij}c_{ij}n_{ij}-B)&=0\\
\mu_{i'j'}n_{i'j'}&=0, \text{ }i'=1,...,N,j'=1,...,M\\
\end{align}
Then, I find that $n_{i'j'}\neq 0$, $\mu_{i'j'}=0$, 
and $\lambda\neq0$, $B=\sum_{ij}c_{ij}n_{ij}$

From the first KKT conditions, I got
\begin{align}
\frac{w_{j'}^2}{2\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^m n_{i'j}w_{j}^{2}}}+\lambda c_{i'j'}=0
\end{align}
Then, I dont know how to proceed.

The following is the optimal solution for the above problem.
\begin{align}
n_{ij}^* =
\begin{cases}
\frac{B}{\frac{c_{ij_{i}^{*}}^2}{w_{j_{i}^{*}}^2}\sum_{l=1}^{N} \frac{w_{j_{l}^{*}}^2}{c_{lj_{l}^{*}}}} & \quad \text{if } j=j_{i}^{*} \\
0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
\text{where }j_{i}^{*}= \underset{j}{\operatorname{arg\,max}}\frac{w_{j}^2}{c_{ij}} \text{ and }i=1,2,...,N
\end{align}

Although I have the optimal solution, I don't how it was done. Could anyone show me the steps? Many thanks.